# Journey Builder: Error binding data bound member

Tags: marketing-cloud

I created a Journey Builder Interaction and turned it on to TEST mode.

The Event Source for the interaction is a sendable Data Extension which is updated (via the API) every time someone new signs up through our website.

Contacts who do not already exist in 'All Subscribers' fail to enter the Journey Builder Interaction, and this is the error thrown:

```
Failed - ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Activities.AllowMultipleDecision.ContactKey: Error binding data bound member.
```

Question #1: Does a contact have to exist in All Subscribers to be accepted into an interaction?

Question #2: How can I add contacts to All Subscribers when they first flow through Journey Builder?

Comment: There are two places a contact may exist: in a data extension linked to an attribute group that is marked Use as Root, or on the All Subscribers list.  Does your sendable data extension have "Use as Root" defined in Contact Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a brief webinar with Fahd to understand what the issue is as there are several reasons why this could be occurring. For the benefit of others, I'm posting the answer here.

In this case, the Channel Address Order was not defined for Send Email Activities. The Channel Address Order determines which channel address field takes precedence for all send Activities.

To define the Channel Address Order for Send Email Activities, select the **Contacts Configuration** menu item in the Contact Builder app and from the **Email** panel click on **Edit**, then **Add Address** and select the Attribute Group containing the email address, then click on **Save**. You can change the precedence of a channel address by dragging the row in the panel. When you're finished, click on **Save**.

Comment: Hi i too facing the same issue.I have used a Dataextension called demo and it has three attributes email,Name,IsTrue.I have created a journey builder which filters users who have checked IsTrue flag.In contacts configuration i have added Demo.Email but still i get the above mentioned error.Can anyone help on it

Comment: Manoj, I'm wondering if this error is actually related to the Contacts Configuration, or something else. If you replace the Send Email Activity in your Journey with something else (like an Update Contact Data Activity), do you still get the same error?

Comment: Hi Eliot ,I replaced send email with update contact but still i am facing same error

Answer (score 0):

When editing your interaction, in the upper left hand corner change Contact Entry from Single to Multiple.  Also, [check this out](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node) for more info on creating custom activities.