# Journey Builder Custom Activity Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm currently developing a custom activity for Journey Builder but have hit an issue I can not resolve.

The activity is appearing in Journey Builder and can be added to an interaction however when it runs, all of the contacts within the DE defined fail with the following error;

> Failed - ExactTarget.JourneyBuilder.Activities.RestActivity.ContactKey: Error binding data bound member.

Googling hasn't thrown up much nor has SFMC documentation. The problem also occurs with the Hello World example on ExactTarget's public Github which makes me think it might be a configuration issue rather than the activity itself but if anyone can offer any suggestions it would be hugely appreciated!

**So far...**

- Activity has no in/out arguments. It simply outputs to console.log whenever the save/validate/publish/execute endpoints fire
- Granted full read/write access in AppCenter
- Ensured the contact model has been configured with a root data DE (Sandbox_Customer) that relates to a Contact Key
- Ensured *Contact Configuration > Email* has been setup correctly with the email address from the Sandbox_Customer DE
- Ensured contacts exists in both subscribers and the Sandbox_Customer DE
- Ensured the journey contact entry is set as multiple
- Followed the suggestions in this question - [Journey Builder: Error binding data bound member](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72696/journey-builder-error-binding-data-bound-member)

Comment: It's SFMC not SFDC - Salesforce Marketing Cloud. Not sure what SFDC is

Comment: We have multiple entries already configured so I believe it's a different issue

Comment: And for clarity, what is mentioned in the link above has already been tried

Comment: I voted to reopen fwiw. Sorry!

Comment: Adam to not have this as a duplicate you'll probably have to update the question with more specifics of what you're trying to do in the custom activity.

Comment: I've added more information on what has been tried so far...hopefully this is enough